pdfjs-dist importing module error despite rest of project importing appropriately
I am trying to introduce the pdfjs-dist library into my nodejs server. However it's giving an import error

Error [ERR_REQUIRE_ESM]: require() of ES Module C:\Users\zjric\auto-filing\node_modules\pdfjs-dist\build\pdf.mjs not supported.
Instead change the require of C:\Users\zjric\auto-filing\node_modules\pdfjs-dist\build\pdf.mjs to a dynamic import() which is available in all CommonJS modules.
    at Object.<anonymous> (C:\Users\zjric\auto-filing\utils\pdf_to_text.js:1:18) {
  code: 'ERR_REQUIRE_ESM'
}


I assume this has to do with my package.json file and the es5/es6 differences shenanigans.
const pdfjsLib = require('pdfjs-dist');

const getTextFromPDF = async (path) =>{
    let doc = await pdfjsLib.getDocument(path).promise;
    let page1 = await doc.getPage(1);
    let content = await page1.getTextContent();
    return content.items.map(function(item){
        return item.str;
    });
}

getTextFromPDF('./demo.pdf').then(data => console.log(data));

module.exports = { getTextFromPDF }

changing my package.json file to "type": "module" isn't realistic as all of my other infrastructure is already formatted in the require('module') and runs perfectly fine. I presume I need to modify the library itself but I'm unaware as to how to manipulate that.

I would usually run into situations like this when working on older project but want to use newer modules with es6 imports/exports.
What I would do in this situation check for a .default in the requiring file. So in your case it would be
const pdfjsLib = require('pdfjs-dist').default and if that doesn't work just use the recommended solution what node recommends which is to use dynamic imports.
Here is an example


const getTextFromPDF = async(path) => {
  const pdfjs = await import ('pdfjs-dist');
  let doc = await pdfjsLib.getDocument(path).promise;
  let page1 = await doc.getPage(1);
  let content = await page1.getTextContent();
  return content.items.map(function(item) {
    return item.str;
  });
}

getTextFromPDF('./demo.pdf').then(data => console.log(data));

module.exports = {
  getTextFromPDF
}




That seemed to work, however now I'm encountering this._compatibility = Promise.withResolvers(); related error. Unsure where its coming from as this is all it points to
let run = async x => await import('pdfjs-dist');

const getTextFromPDF = async (path) =>{
    let pdfjsLib = await run();
    let doc = await pdfjsLib.getDocument(path).promise;
    let page1 = await doc.getPage(1);
    let content = await page1.getTextContent();
    return content.items.map(function(item){
        return item.str;
    });
}


I am not sure how you are using the file elswhere but it could be the module.exports  returning unresolved promise by the time the getTextFromPDF is exported.

Hey @jamesed, sorry for the latent response: I doesn't appear to be anything with module.exports as far as I can tell. I've created a github gist because sharing code within comments is pretty rough. gist url

@nebulous looks like that error could be your version of node. See this https://github.com/vercel/next.js/discussions/62122#discussioncomment-9458763

You're amazing! I couldn't find anything related to the problem im on v20.5 so thanks so much!
